# Automating a text change on every html page of a website

Tags: python, html, automation

I'm using Siteimprove which is a software that looks through a website and recommends accessibility changes. I'm supposed to go through and edit the html of the pages to improve the Siteimprove score.

I'm supposed to add a language attribute to all 143 pages and I was thinking I could write a simple script to go through every html page and replace `<html>` with `<html lang="en-US">` instead of manually do this.

I haven't done this before so I was thinking to make a copy and test a script (I have yet to write). Do you know where I should look for examples to write such a script that would basically say:

"For every file in directory named .html, if it contains `<html>` replace `<html>` with `<html lang="en-US">`"

Or if I should edit my logic statement above? I'm a student worker and don't want to mess this up.

Comment: You can do batch repalce in all opened file in notepad++

Comment: you can use any editor to replaceAll like sublime, VSCode, notepadd++ any of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you to those who left comments, I didn't realize replaceAll was an option in VSCode, much easier solution!